# Laravel: model id goes to true before update

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I've got quite a bizarre situation. I've got a piece of code that never gave any issues in the past. Since last night it behaves like this.

Before updating a model the id of that model goes to true. The function below is from a controller and gets called with a POST request. The request gets validated and when the model has not been exported it gets exported to another system. If the export is successful, the model gets updated with the appropriate values. The id does not get set in any stage of this process.

I've added comments to the code to give you an idea where, what happens.

```
    public function export(Request $request, VeniceService $service, Invoice $invoice)
    {
        $invoice = $invoice->load([
            'user', 'customer', 'extension.referenceValues.definition', 'lines'
        ]);
        $this->enforce([
            new CheckCstNum($invoice->customer),
            new CheckReferences($invoice->extension),
        ], 432);

        if ($invoice->to_export) {
            DB::beginTransaction();
            try {
                var_dump($invoice->id); // returns the id
                $data = $service->export($invoice);
                var_dump($invoice->id); // returns the true
                $invoice->book_date = Carbon::now();
                $invoice->doc_num = $data['doc_num'];
                $invoice->sys_num = $data['sys_num'];
                $invoice->tsm_num = $data['tsm_num'];

                $invoice->to_export = false;
                $invoice->is_ticked = false;


                var_dump($invoice->id); // This returns true
                var_dump($invoice); // All the values are correct, except the id, this is set to true

                $invoice->save(); // With the id as true, this throws an exception. Duplicate entries for PRIMARY key id, '1'

                DB::commit();
                $service->attachPdf($invoice, Printer::print($invoice)->output());
            } catch (VeniceException $e) {
                DB::rollBack();
                return $e->render($request);
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                DB::rollBack();
                return response()->json($e->getMessage(), 500);
            }
        }

        return new InvoiceResource($invoice->refresh()); // returns the invoice, but the id is still true
    }
```

`$this->service->export()` resolves to this function. Before this happens, the id is still the original id of the model.

```
    public function export($model)
    {
        return $this->call($model, __FUNCTION__);
    }

    protected function call($model, $function)
    {
        $class = $this->getClassName($model);
        $method = "{$function}{$class}";
        return $this->$method($model);
    }

    public function exportInvoice($invoice)
    {
        var_dump($invoice->id); // Returns the id
        $veniceInvoice = (new VeniceInvoiceResource($invoice))->toArray(request());
        var_dump($invoice->id); // Returns true...

        return $this->request('POST', 'venice/invoices/' . $this->bookSales, [
            RequestOptions::JSON => $veniceInvoice
        ]);
    }
```

`$veniceInvoice = (new VeniceInvoice($invoice))->toArray(request());` After this line the id is set as true. This really does not make any sense as it has always worked, and the model does not get manipulated in any way.

One last bit of code. But I do not think this has anything to do with the issue.

VeniceInvoiceResource.php

```
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        $pdf = Printer::print($this->resource)->output();

        $lines = $this->customer->standard_base == 10 ? VeniceInvoiceLineIC::collection($this->lines) : VeniceInvoiceLine::collection($this->lines);
        $refs = $this->extension->referenceValues->map(function ($item) {
            return [
                'index' => 0,
                'quantity' => 0,
                'unit_price' => 0,
                'description' => $item->definition->name . ' ' . $item->value,
                'vat_code' => 0,
                'ic_code' => 0,
            ];
        })->toArray();

        $details = array_merge($refs, $lines->toArray($request));

        return [
            'cst_num' => $this->customer->cst_num,
            'book' => ($this->book === 'VKPCN') ? $this->book : config('venice.config.sales.book'),
            'amount' => $this->total,
            'vat_amount' => $this->total,
            'exp_date' => carbon(config('venice.config.sales.date'))->addDays($this->customer->exp_term)->format('d/m/Y'),
            'doc_date' => carbon(config('venice.config.sales.date'))->format('d/m/Y'),
            'vat_system' => $this->customer->vat_system,
            'bf_code' => $this->customer->bf_code,
            'doc_type' => ($this->doc_type === 'slsCreditnote') ? 1 : 0, 
            'pdf' => base64_encode($pdf),
            'pdfName' => $this->date->format('Ym') . '-' . $this->id . '.pdf',
            'remark' => 'Clockwork ' . $this->date->format('Y F') . ' ' . $this->user->name,
            'details' => $details,
        ];
    }
```

For now I've added a temporary fix to mitigate the issue. I've created a clone of the $invoice. later I set the id of the original invoice to the cloned invoice id.

```
...
    $invoice_copy = clone $invoice;

    if ($invoice->to_export) {
        DB::beginTransaction();
        try {
            $data = $service->export($invoice);

            $invoice->book_date = Carbon::now();
            $invoice->doc_num = $data['doc_num'];
            $invoice->sys_num = $data['sys_num'];
            $invoice->tsm_num = $data['tsm_num'];

            $invoice->to_export = false;
            $invoice->is_ticked = false;
            $invoice->id = $invoice_copy->id;
            $invoice->save();
            DB::commit();
...
```

After a lot of debugging I have pinpointed where the id is set to true. I still don't know why.

In VeniceInvoiceResource `$this->id` before the PDF generation, the id is still the original invoice id. After the Printer, the id is`true`.

If I look at the contructor for the resources, found in `Illuminat\Http\Resources\JsonResource` (Resource extends JsonResource) I see that `$this->resource` is set to the incomming value, in this case the `$invoice`.

```
    /**
     * Create a new resource instance.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $resource
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($resource)
    {
        $this->resource = $resource;
    }
```

While in `VeniceInvoiceResource` $this->resource gets passed to the Printer instance. In the resource `$this` also has the values of the invoice.

```
    /**
     * Load items to print.
     *
     * @param $items
     * @return $this
     * @throws \Illuminate\Contracts\Filesystem\FileNotFoundException
     */
    public function print($items, $toPrint = null)
    {
        $items = is_array($items) || $items instanceof Collection ? $items : func_get_args();

        foreach ($items as $item) {
            if ($item instanceof Printable) {
                foreach ($item->printData($toPrint) as $key => $data) {
                    switch($key) {
                        case 'merge':
                            $this->mergeOutput($data);
                            break;
                        case 'mergeFile':
                            $this->mergeFile($data);
                            break;
                        default:
                            $this->toPrint[] = $this->view->make($key, $data)->render();
                    }
                }
            } elseif ($item instanceof Renderable) {
                $this->toPrint[] = $item->render();
            } elseif (is_string($item)) {
                $this->toPrint[] = $item;
            } else {
                throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Invalid argument');
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
```

In the print method, `$this->toPrint[] = $this->view->make($key, $data)->render();` gets used in this case. The output method looks like this.

```
    /**
     * Get the output as string.
     *
     * @return string
     * @throws \iio\libmergepdf\Exception
     */
    public function output()
    {
        return $this->generate();
    }

    /**
     * Generate and merge.
     *
     * @return string
     * @throws \iio\libmergepdf\Exception
     */
    protected function generate()
    {
        $data = !empty($this->toPrint) ? $this->toPrint : [''];
        $result = $this->pdf->getOutputFromHtml($data); 

        if (!empty($this->toMerge)) {
            $this->merger->addRaw($result);

            foreach ($this->toMerge as $item) {
                $this->merger->addRaw($item);
            }
            $result = $this->merger->merge();
        }

        $this->toPrint = null;
        $this->toMerge = null;

        return $result;
    }
```

In the print service nothing gets manipulated, it simply prints collections and items to a PDF format.

The last edit, because I found the line that caused all this. But I don't fully understand why it sets the id to true.

In `Printer::print` there is a call to a method on the model, `printData()` this method has an if statement to solve a problem we had with two invoices that needed some special treatment. There was not much time so we decided a simple if statement was sufficient enough for this situation.

```
        if ($this->id = 4128 || $this->id === 4217) {
            $vat_amount = 0;
            $vat_label = '';
        }
```

if you look closely you see that the first condition is not a condition... There is the problem, and the fix was simple. Remove this if statement as we don't need it any more. The invoices `4128 & 4217` already got printed and are archived. They do not need to be processed anymore.

Comment: Whats its value before and after the array_merge?

Comment: @MattJameson I will provide the values in a bit. I'm not in the office a.t.m.

Comment: Does not seem reasonable but put `$data = $service->export($invoice);` before `\DB::beginTransaction()` as it has nothing related to DB.

Comment: A bit complicated to read but you're making a request to another system and that is what is returning true to you if im correct? if so, the issue is on the other side

Comment: @abr I don't think so, as `$invoice` model has not been passed to `export` function here (`$data = $service->export($invoice);` by reference, so it's properties must not change outside of the first call in the controller.

Comment: Show me your resource for the invoice @ako

Comment: @ako `$invoice` is an object. All objects are passed by reference. So, if the `$invoice->id` is changed anywhere in the callstack, the change would be seen in the calling function.

Comment: @IlyasDeckers What does the `VeniceInvoiceResource` constructor look like?

Comment: @abr It is no issue with the external service. The external service returns an array with values, these values get set on the invoice. The invoice id is already true at this point. What I still don't understand is that it never gave any issues. On the other hand, I took over this project and most of the code isn't mine. Maybe I broke something on the last update. I am rolling back to a previous release locally right now, to see if the issue is still present.

Comment: @patricus The resource does not have a contructor.

Comment: @MattJameson The value before and after the `array_merge` are exactly the same. The id is right. I've narrowed down the issue to the function `exportInvoice()` Before the Resource is called, the id has not changed. After the id is true. I'll update my question with this information.

Comment: I would have thought `VeniceInvoiceResource` had a constructor as it is accepting params

Comment: @MattJameson VeniceInvoiceResource extends Resource. the constructor is used from the Resource written by the Laravel devs. 
I'm quite sure the issue is in the VeniceInvoiceResource. The `$this` object has true as id after the Printer::print() call. This Printer does not change any values. It only creates a PDF from the given values. I'll keep testing and update the question if I find relevant information.

Comment: @IlyasDeckers Have you checked `$this->resource->id` before and after the call to `Printer::print($this->resource)->output()`? If it's changed, what does the printer `print()` method look like?

Comment: @patricus I've updated my question with the print function and some other information that could be relevant. `$this->resource->id` has the same behaviour as `$this->id`. After the print() method the id is true.

Comment: I finally found it... For the answer, look at the last part of the question.

Comment: @IlyasDeckers Glad you found it. My next question was going to to be what was in the `printData()` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you found the issue in your `printData()` method.

For why `id` ends up as `true`, it's due to the differing [operator precedences](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php).

The comparison operators (`===`) have a higher precedence than the logical operator (`||`), so the comparisons are done before the logical comparison. So, if the comparison operator had been correct, this is what would have been run (parens added for clarity):

```
($this->id === 4128) || ($this->id === 4217)
```

However, because the first operator was actually an assignment instead of a comparison, this changed the order of operation. The comparion and logical operators have a higher precedence than the assignment operator, so they are executed first. This is what was actually run (parens added for clarity):

```
$this->id = (4128 || $this->id === 4217)
```

So, `id` got assigned to the result of the logical comparison. Since all non-zero numbers evaluate to `true`, the logical comparison evaluated to `true`, and therefore `id` got set to `true`.